# <div> following a responsive Image

Tags: html, css, responsive

and thank you for your time in advance!

I am working on a site (here):
https://www.flighteducation.co.uk/Panelcraft/index.php

The HTML is:

```
<div class="w3-content w3-section">
<div class="static">
<img src="img/Head Plain.webp">
</div>
<div class="fade">
<img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img/Head Logo.webp">
<img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img/Head Round.webp">
<img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img/Head Square.webp">
</div>
</div>
```

The top cross-fading images are responsive to the page width with the CSS code (both .fade and .static) being:

```
.fade{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 179px;
}

.fade img{
width: 100%;
}
```

"How can I write more code after the image that sticks to the bottom of it?"

Am finding myself popping a huge position: relative number after it to get it below, and then of course when the screen width shrinks...the following item stays still vertically.

I understand this is quite a simple question...but I'm stumped!

Thanks again.

Comment: Sticks to the bottom of what?

Comment: To the area at the bottom of the image carousel (maybe a bottom margin of 30px for instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better not use `position: absolute;`

And `top: 10vh;` is a better use than `top: 120px;` because the `vh` is screen relative, and for me easier to handle.

If this image is the only element in this div, wouldn't it be easier to put the image as a background for this div ?

Comment: The main div has two sets of divs within it. 1 (static) - a static picture and 2 (fade)- three images fading over the top to create the crossfade effect. Removing the Position allows the document flow to work, but then I get issues with overlapping the two divs as well as images won't goto 100% width.

Comment: Talking about the .static div

Comment: GENIUS!! That was mind-blowing! Can't thank you enough Shachar297!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply *don't*  use `position: absolute;` –  it takes the element out of the document flow, with the effect you are experiencing.

Comment: You are right regarding the document flow, but removing that makes the images drop to about 50% of their size, even with a width 100% in CSS. Also the two won't sit over each other...'fade' drops below static. It's crazy how something so simple can get messy!